# Did Sheikh Mujibur Rahman, leader of the Awami league win any seats in West Pakistan in the 1971 elections?

Tags: india, pakistan, south-asia

The Awami League, the largest East Pakistani political party, led by Sheikh Mujibur Rahman, won a landslide victory in the national elections in 1970. The party won 167 of the 169 seats allotted to East Pakistan, and thus a majority of the 313 seats in the National Assembly. That they were blocked from doing so led to the 1971 liberation war of Bangladesh.

Did they win any seats in West Pakistan?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The *Pakistani General Election of 1970* (delayed in East Pakistan/Bangladesh until Jan 1971 due to flooding) resulted in no seats for the *Bangladesh Awami League* in West Pakistan.

The polarised geographic concentration of party influence (BAL in the East, PPP in the West) lead to the *Bangladesh Liberation War*.

Comment: This answer took five minutes of browsing Wikipedia